# Que veut dire l'expression « make sure that all i's are dotted and t's crossed » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

J'ai entendu plusieurs fois cette expression, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une traduction Française qui reflète le sens (dont je ne suis pas totalement sûr moi-même).

De la façon dont je le vois, ça reviendrait à s'assurer que tout est en ordre, mais je ne suis pas encore convaincu, et les dictionnaires en ligne ainsi que Google me donnent des résultats assez farfelus.

Comment traduiriez-vous cela, dans vos propres mots ?

Comment: Hors sujet pour moi: on peut aider à trouver une expression française équivalent à une expression anglaise quand le questionneur connait le sens qu'il veut utiliser, mais pas passer en revue les différents sens potentiel d'une expression anglaise (la compétence se trouve dans _English Language and Usage_, mais il faut questionner en anglais et accepter les réponses dans cette langue).

Comment: @Unfrancophone: tout à fait d'accord. Une fois que le sens est clarifié (et éventuellement débattu) sur EL&U, si trouver une façon d'exprimer ça en français pose vraiment problème, alors on peut rouvrir la question. Mais il faut d'abord qu'il y ait un consensus sur le sens de l'expression anglaise.

Comment: Cela signifie (re)vérifier et s'assurer que tout est parfait, qu'il n'y a rien à critiquer. Faire en sorte que tout soit “carré” pourrait être une expression française similaire.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

La traduction presque littérale est correcte :

> Mettre les points sur les « i » (et les barres aux « t »).

Cela signifie être pointilleux*, s'intéresser aux détails.

*Ce mot viendrait-il de l'expression ?

Comment: Pour moi l'expression française ne veut pas dire ça ! Ça veut dire expliquer très clairement quelque chose à quelqu'un qui ne comprend pas ou ne veut pas comprendre (je ne fais que reprendre [les mots de Wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mettre_les_points_sur_les_i)).

Answer (score -2):

Traduction intuitive, selon le contexte :

> S'assurer que tout est pointé et vérifié.
>   S'assurer que tout est fixé et verrouillé.

avec une préférence pour la première.

**Complément** 
Cela fait penser aux bandes de totalisation comptables que l'ont joint à un paquet de documents :

- le premier pointe la liste et les documents en mettant un barre horizontale ou oblique à coté du chiffre vérifié,
- le second fait une seconde barre en croix pour valider la vérification du premier.

La seconde pourrait s'appliquer à quelque matériel que l'on accroche et sécurise avant une mise en route.

Comment: Ça ne me semble pas idiomatique, et rien ne dit que c'est le sens de l'expression originale.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez , j'ai corrigé par *fait une seconde barre en croix* : pointer pour un comptable, c'est mettre un signe à coté d'un chiffre, souvent une barre oblique (quelquefois recourbée en forme de v déséquilibré) - Dans ce contexte, il n'y a pas "choix" mais "contrôle" par [contre/re-]pointage.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Rien, à part bien sûr une connaissance minimale de l'anglais.