# Traduction appropriée de « get this task out the door »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Dans mon entreprise précédente, un de mes collègues employait toujours l'expression « *to get this task out the door* », dans le contexte de la fin d'un projet.

La traduction la plus proche que j'ai réussi à trouver était « se débarrasser de cette tâche », mais cela a une connotation négative. La traduction que je cherche exprimerait bien le fait qu'il s'agit de terminer une tâche, et de ne plus avoir à s'en préoccuper par la suite. J'ai également l'impression que cette expression reflète une notion d'urgence, mais je suis peut-être biaisé par le contexte dans lequel j'ai entendu cette expression.

Comment exprimeriez-vous cette notion en Français ?

Comment: Comme [ailleurs](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/que-veut-dire-lexpression-make-sure-that-all-is-are-dotted-and-ts-crossed?rq=1), il serait bon que le sens de l'expression soit clair avant qu'on ait une chance de la traduire correctement. -1 pour ça. Encouragements pour obtenir plus de renseignements, sur EL&U par exemple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S'il s'agit d'une fin de projet (fin d'une *charrette*, mot employé par les architectes sur un projet qui mobilise toutes les énergies et que l'on doit rendre dans un temps donné)

- Finissons-en avec ce travail
- Terminons-le à temps (ou : vite, rapidement)

En associant les deux personnes, le contexte péjoratif est éliminé.

La seconde traduction remplace la porte par le temps, ce qui semble "coller" à l'expression originelle.

Answer (score 3):

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi *se débarrasser* ne te convient pas, puisque c'est bien de cela dont il s'agit dans l'expression originelle. Une alternative peut être *se délester*.

Comment: Je trouve "se débarasser" assez péjoratif et me fait penser à quelqu'un qui en a marre d'une tâche et veut juste la terminer pour être tranquille. Mais peut-être que cette expression Anglaise a également une connotation négative?

Comment: @linker : oui en effet. C'est littéralement "le mettre à la porte"

Answer (score 3):

Voici les phrases françaises qui me semblent s'en rapprocher :

- On va régler son compte à cette tâche [un peu humoristique]
- On va expédier cette tâche vite fait bien fait. [sous entend la rapidité]
- On va mettre cette tâche/ce travail derrière nous.

Answer (score 0):

Dans un contexte professionnel, je parlerais de clôturer une tâche.

> Clôturons cette tâche